# Texto com acento cortado

Tags: bug, acentuação, stackexchange-button

Quando o texto tem acento e ele é cortado fica um caractere falho:

[image: texto cortado]

Texto original:

> @GuilhermeNascimento Isso. Os modelos de jogos mais "rentáveis" são aqueles onde você paga para avançar

Isso deve ser porque os acentos usam UNICODE e o efeito "elide" não consegue interpreta-los.